# Issue in Overriding Magento_Contact's form.phtml file

Tags: magento2, theme, contact-us, overriding

I want to override the form.phtml file from the magento's core contact module using my custom theme. So i created a folder structure like below,

```
app/design/frontend/Ziffity/Weight/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml
```

Then i copied the core module's form.phtml into the above folder structure and edited placeholder/label of the form according to my needs.

Core module's folder structure is below

```
vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml
```

I have cleared browser cache and magento cache using below commands..

```
sudo rm -Rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -Rf pub/static/*
sudo rm -Rf generated/*
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```

But the changes are not taking effect. I don't know what i am doing wrong here. as i am following all the instructions correctly.

**Note: I also believe, i don't need to register my custom theme for overriding .phtml or html templates.**

Please guide me, what i am doing wrong here.

Note: Changes i made in form.phtml was very simple ones..

Comment: Please register your theme and try once it will be working fine.

Comment: I registered the custom theme by creating theme.xml and registration.php and providing magento/luma as my parent theme. But all sample products in magento are gone after changing to my new theme. Any suggestion for above issue...? Anyway thanks for ur comment..

Comment: Yes you have to set your theme in admin Content > Design > Configuration > Edit Default Store View Theme and set your custom theme into it.

Comment: please configure your theme in the Admin panel and  check with small caps for the 'Weight' folders with all required changes .